# Comparing ints and floats in pandas vs python is inconsistent. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, types

Pandas is doing something weird with `dtypes` here and I am trying to figure out why...

Here is an example `pd.DataFrame`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]]).T.convert_dtypes()
```

It's `df.dtypes` are:

```
0      Int64
1    float64
dtype: object
```

I need to verify if the columns are the correct datatypes, so I do the following:

```
df[1].dtype == float
```

I get `True`. When I do this for the `0` (`int`) column:

```
df[0].dtype == int
```

I get `False`

The only way to "verify" the `int` type it seems to be if I do this: `df[0].dtype == pd.core.arrays.integer.Int64Dtype()`

**Question**: Why the inconsistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has [`is_integer_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_integer_dtype.html) just for this:

```
df.dtypes

0      Int64
1    float64
dtype: object

# Both of these work. You can either pass a column or dtype 
pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(df[0])
pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(df.dtypes[0])
# True
```

Checking floats would be done with [`is_float_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_float_dtype.html). There are similar function for testing other dtypes, peruse the documentation for more.

Comment: Can I in the same way test if a datetime object is of timezone utc? I see this exists `is_datetime64tz_dtype` but this does not specify the tz.

Comment: @Newskooler Not familiar with any function to do that, although couldn't you just extract the timezone info from your datetime objects and compare them somehow? Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706499/checking-if-date-is-in-utc-format) could help.

Comment: Current I do it like so: `df['time'].dtype == pd.core.dtypes.dtypes.DatetimeTZDtype(tz=timezone.utc)` but what you are suggesting may be more robust. I will try.

Comment: @Newskooler did you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706499/checking-if-date-is-in-utc-format) as well? If nothing works, please feel free to open a new question! Did you have any other questions about the code posted above?

Comment: Thanks for all. That help!